# How do i update a label or button color from console.log response

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there all i had some great help from people last night and have been trying to continue the project today at hte moment i am almost there i just need to be able to change the color of the button on this HTML page depending on the  stats of the conole.log

```
<html>
            <head>

            <style>
                input.MyButton {
                width: 300px;
                padding: 25px;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 150%;
                background: #3366cc;
                color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #white;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding-bottom:25px;
                }
                input.MyButton:hover {
                color: #ffff00;
                background: #000;
                border: 1px solid #fff;
                }
            </style>

            </head>
    <body>

    <form>

        <br>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Office Light" onclick="togglelight('126')" />
        <br>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Fishtank Light" onclick="togglelight('128')" />
        <br>
        <label id ="officestatus">This</label>


    </form>


    </body>

<script type="text/javascript">
                function togglelight(ipstr) {
                  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                      console.log(this.responseText); //To check output while error[Optional]
                      (#"=officestatus").append("hello"); 

                    }
                  };
                  xhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1."+ipstr+"/cm?cmnd=Power%20toggle", true);
                  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is response text a `json` with different values or just the color?

Comment: post a sample output of **this.responseText**

Comment: `(#"=officestatus")` this is not valid syntax. Perhaps you meant `$('#officestatus')`. Though this would assume that you are using jQuery, but you don't load the library anywhere in your code.

Comment: Response is just a different color

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some syntax issues first. :)

```
<style>
 input.MyButton {
 // ...
 border: 1px solid #white;
```

should be `border: 1px solid white;` or `#fff`

And also `(#"=officestatus").append("hello");` is not valid syntax. The way to do this without jQuery (even though now it is present in all browsers) is `document.querySelector("#officestatus").append("hello");` or `document.getElementById("officestatus").append("hello");`.

And lastly, in order to achieve what you want with changing the color of a button, I would recommend doing it like this:

- create new CSS classes that controls the styling of the button in

```
input.buttonStyle1 {
 background: red; // or any color you wish
}

input.buttonStyle2 {
 background: green; 
}
```

- then add the class to the button depending on the value that you wish to check

```
if (this.responseText === "someValue") {

 document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add("buttonStyle1");

} else if (this.responseText === "someOtherValue") {

 document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add("buttonStyle2");

}
```

PS: By the way, I recommend adding an id to each button to differentiate between them. :)

PSS: You could do some nifty stuff like making the `responseText` be the name of the class that should be added to the button:

```
document.querySelector("input.MyButton").classList.add(responseText);
```

but you would also need to declare each possible class in your stylesheet.

Comment: Mate looks like what i need, but my mistake i wanted to replace the text not append, i have tried to replace .append with .value.text and just text and.value and getting errors

Comment: i have been trying to get it working all morning and keep getting errors, i am sure it something silly i am doing

https://codeshare.io/axweLD